# GPU Issue after updating drivers

Tags: drivers, video, gpu

Usually games on my PC work perfectly. However after updating all the PC drivers (including Intel(R) HD graphics), games won't work properly, they are slow and graphics are low, I have an example.

Here are the details:

[image: Minimum System Requirements error message]

[image: PC Info dialog]

Comment: Intel HD graphics is not intended for gaming - its a low energy GPU (built into the CPU as far as I recall) designed for laptops to minimise power consumption. If you want to do gaming your best bet is a laptop with a dedicated graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

The latest [Intel drivers](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/06/26/new-intel-iris-iris-pro-and-hd-graphics-driver-update-posted-for-haswell-and) have a registry key to simulate memory.

> The graphics driver now reports some amount of fictitious “dedicated”
>   graphics memory to the operating system (128MB by default) to work
>   around applications issues in a number of games. These games
>   incorrectly look for some amount of “dedicated” graphics memory
>   because they weren’t coded with the unified memory architecture for
>   processor graphics.
>
> The amount reported can be modified or disabled if desired by changing
>   the following registry value:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel\GMM, create a REG_DWORD value named
>   “DedicatedSegmentSize”. The value is interpreted as number of MB to
>   report (0-512MB). A value of 0 disables reporting the dummy memory
>   segment. If the registry key/value is not found, the driver will
>   report the default 128MB.

So, create the DWORD 32Bit `DedicatedSegmentSize` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel\GMM` and set it o 512 (Decimal).

Now try to run the game.

Comment: Thank you for your information, you actually gave me hope. However I'm afraid I couldn't find the GMM folder in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel!
Is there some other name to it?

Comment: I can't find the GMM folder in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel! Does it have another name?

Comment: create the key and the DWORD with regedit.exe if you can't find it

Comment: I've done it, I've set it on 512 (Decimal), but whenever I try to check again i find it Hexadecima! the game still won't work.

Comment: ask it in the Intel community so that the Intel developers can fix it: https://communities.intel.com/message/310103#310103